# Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.4

I got this error when flushed cache storage of magento

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`mysite`.`core_cache_tag`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_CACHE_TAG` FOREIGN KEY (`cache_id`) REFERENCES `mysite`.`core_cache` (`id`))

I tried to 

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE core_cache_tag;
TRUNCATE core_cache;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

but no luck when i flushed again.
```

Comment: can you upload the FK declaration?

Comment: If this is not a live environment, then try restarting mysql and try the sql query above again

Comment: @R.S: I tried to restart mysql, and no luck too

Comment: FK = foreing key, the sql that define the relation between the 2 tables

Comment: Try doing a `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; delete from core_cache_tag where tag is not NULL; SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;`

Comment: @IvanButtinoni: How can i find it?

Comment: @kevin-nguyen dinner time :) 
show create table table1; show create table table2; ...

Comment: anyone on this?